# FullCalendar - How to disable the drag functionality to adjust the duration of a new event when creating it

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, fullcalendar

Hello i'm using full calendar in angular, I want to make it so that when the user clicks on an empty schedule in the calendar (which is a weekly calendar, and each date interval is 15 minutes), they can't hold the click and define the duration of the event. Unfortunately chatpgt cannot help me in this case as it only shows information up to 2020, and this library continues to be updated to date.

here is my html code:

```
<div class='demo-app'>
                    <div class='demo-app-main'>
                      <full-calendar *ngIf='calendarVisible' [options]='calendarOptions' >
                      <ng-template #eventContent let-arg>
                          <b>{{ arg.timeText }}</b>
                          <i>{{ arg.event.title }}</i>
                      </ng-template>
                      </full-calendar>
                    </div>
                </div>
</div>
```

And here is my .ts calendarOptions definition:

```
  calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
    plugins: [
      interactionPlugin,
      dayGridPlugin,
      timeGridPlugin,
      listPlugin,
    ],
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'timeGridWeek'
    },
    initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
    slotMinTime: '08:00:00',     
    slotMaxTime: '21:00:00',     
    slotDuration: '00:15:00',    
    slotLabelInterval: '00:15:00', 
    slotLabelFormat: {           
      hour: '2-digit',
      minute: '2-digit',
      hour12: true,
    },
    contentHeight: 'auto',      
    aspectRatio: 1.5,
    firstDay: 1,
    weekends: true,
    editable: false,
    selectable: false,
    selectMirror: true,
    dayMaxEvents: true,
    allDaySlot: false,
    dayHeaderFormat: {           
      weekday: 'short',
      day: '2-digit',
      month: '2-digit'
    },
    locales: [esLocale],
    businessHours: {           
      daysOfWeek: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 
      startTime: '09:00',        
      endTime: '21:00',          
    },
    select: this.handleDateSelect.bind(this),
    eventClick: this.handleEventClick.bind(this),
    eventsSet: this.handleEvents.bind(this),
    datesSet: this.handleDatesSet.bind(this)
  };
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to ensure that every event has a duration of exactly 15 minutes?

Comment: @ADyson no, i change the duration of the event in another modal, i just don't want to let the users to choose the duration by draggin the event.

Comment: If you change it afterwards anyway, then why does it matter what the user does with dragging?

Comment: Because the client doesn't like it jajaja

Comment: Ok. Well you could use [selectAllow](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selectAllow) to detect when the selected duration (i.e. the difference between start and end) is not 15 minutes and disallow the selection by returning `false` in that case.

Comment: Thanks man! i didn't see that attribute on the calendar docs :O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to solve this issue, like @ADyson says, just add the selectAllow attribute to your calendarOptions object:
selectAllow: this.handleDragEvent.bind(this)

```
    //Your other attributes...
    selectAllow: this.handleDragEvent.bind(this)
    // ....
```

Then, add the function in your class, mine verifies that the new event doesn't have a duration of more than 15 minutes, if your calendar have a different slot duration just set the difference to that slot duration

```
  handleDragEvent(selectInfo: DateSelectArg): boolean {
    const diffInMilliseconds = Math.abs(selectInfo.end.getTime()- 
  selectInfo.start.getTime());
    const diffInMinutes = Math.floor(diffInMilliseconds / (1000 * 60));

    return diffInMinutes <= 15;
  }
```